# Calculate age based on birthday with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate how old a person is with jQuery. I tried using this code but I am not getting any results. I assume that I cannot but a varible in  date(). What could I do to make this work?

```
<p id="age">2015/01/01</p>


var ptag = $('#age');
var birthdate = new Date(ptag);
var cur = new Date();
var diff = cur-birthdate;
var age = Math.floor(diff/31536000000);
alert(age);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the *contents* of the `#age` element, not the element itself.

`var ptag = $('#age').text();`

Comment: Thanks alot for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
var age = new Date() - new Date($('#age').text());
age /= 31536000000;
```

$(selector).text() will return the content of a DOM element as a text.
And since we do not want to use a bunch of variables, we simply define one, as the difference of two dates: the 'now' minus the one from the text.
And since the above is in miliseconds, we devied it... and that will return age in years.

[jQuery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how your code answers the question. This will help the OP and future searchers understand your answer better.